# Join two tables, group by column and get all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

**Update: Here is the schema :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6447

I have 2 tables:

**posts:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|   post_id  | post_creator_id  |      post_title     |  
-------------------------------------------------------
|    1       |        100       |   Hello All         |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    2       |        14        |   Good morning      |  
-------------------------------------------------------
|    3       |        213       |   Lovely Day        |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    4       |        55        |   Nice Title!       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**comments:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| comment_id | post_id  | commenter_id | comment_text |       date           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    8       |    1     |      98      | Hello world  |  2018-04-27 12:02:22 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    9       |    4     |      123     |    Hi all    |  2018-04-27 13:11:11 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    10      |    4     |      77      | Looking good |  2018-04-27 13:20:17 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    11      |    1     |      101     | Great idea   | 2018-04-27 14:45:15  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the end result I want to have the last comments (comment_text) for each post, and some information about the post (post_title, post_creator_id).
and the date from comments (not from posts - so that I can sort it by last comment date)
So in the above example, the result should be

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  comment_id | post_id | commenter_id|  comment_text  | post_creator_id  |      post_title     |       date          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     10      |   4     |     77      |  Looking good  |       55         |    Nice Title!      | 2018-04-27 13:20:17 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     11      |   1     |    101      |   Great idea   |      100         | Hello All           | 2018-04-27 14:45:15 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So what I am able to do is to join posts with comments but I dont know how to add that additional information (post_title and post_creator_id).

This is my query:

```
select a.*
from comments a
join (
    select post_id, max(date_entered) as date_entered
    from comments
    group by (post_id)
    ) b on a.post_id = b.post_id and a.date_entered = b.date_entered
```

which gives:

```
comment_id    post_id     commenter_id   comment_text         date_entered
----------- -----------   -----------   -------------------- -----------------------
   10          4              77             Looking good     2018-04-27 13:20:17.000
   11          1              101            Great idea       2018-04-27 14:45:15.000
```

But I am lacking the "post_title" and "post_creator_id" columns, and I don't know how can I do another join to add them? What is the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I dont know if I can get a more minimal example that that :O

Comment: Maybe read the linked answer first

Comment: Thank you, I just added a schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to join the `posts` table into your (slightly broken, now corrected) query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6447/28)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
Create table posts(
    post_id  int,
    post_creator_id int,   
  post_title  varchar(100)  
);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES (1, 100, 'Hello All');
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (2, 14,'Good morning');
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (3, 213, 'Lovely Day');
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (4, 55, 'Nice Title!');

create table comments(
    comment_id int,
    post_id int,
    commenter_id int,
    comment_text  varchar(100),
    date  datetime
);

insert into comments values (8 , 1, 98, 'Hello world', '2018-04-27 12:02:22' );
insert into comments values (9 , 4, 123, 'Hi all', '2018-04-27 13:11:11' );
insert into comments values (10 , 4, 77, 'Looking good', '2018-04-27 13:20:17' );
insert into comments values (11 , 1, 101, 'Great idea', '2018-04-27 14:45:15' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
select a.*, p.post_title, p.post_creator_id
from comments a
join (
  select post_id, max(date) as date_entered
  from comments
  group by (post_id)
  ) b on a.post_id = b.post_id and a.date = b.date_entered
join posts p on p.post_id = b.post_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6447/28/0)**:

```
| comment_id | post_id | commenter_id | comment_text |                 date |  post_title | post_creator_id |
|------------|---------|--------------|--------------|----------------------|-------------|-----------------|
|         11 |       1 |          101 |   Great idea | 2018-04-27T14:45:15Z |   Hello All |             100 |
|         10 |       4 |           77 | Looking good | 2018-04-27T13:20:17Z | Nice Title! |              55 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve that by adding this to your sub-query.

```
select a.*
from comments a
join (
    select post_id, max(date_entered) as date_entered, post_title, post_creator_id
    from comments
    group by (post_id)
    ) b on a.post_id = b.post_id and a.date_entered = b.date_entered
```

Comment: but post_title and post_creator_id are from posts and not comments, so I get "Unknown column 'post_title'  and 'post_creator_id'"

Comment: yes they are from posts... comments doesn't have those two columns? I am very confused what exactly you are wanting. What do you mean "Unknown column"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I try to read it with PHP code so it tells me that it doesn't exist. and comments dont have them

Comment: can you export the sample data and temporarily link it on a file sharing site (like https://expirebox.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
       INNER JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id 
WHERE  comments.comment_id IN (SELECT Max(comment_id) 
                               FROM   comments 
                               GROUP  BY post_id);
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6447/33/1

Output

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+
| post_id | post_creator_id | post_title  | comment_id | post_id | commenter_id | comment_text |         date         |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+
|       4 |              55 | Nice Title! |         10 |       4 |           77 | Looking good | 2018-04-27T13:20:17Z |
|       1 |             100 | Hello All   |         11 |       1 |          101 | Great idea   | 2018-04-27T14:45:15Z |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+
```